# Open IIS Management in Windows 7 laptop but no GUI shown

Tags: iis

I installed all IIS features in my Windows 7 laptop.(Turn on in Control Panel).
However it doesn' t show up the GUI after I click IIS manager. I am sure that the process is running. And I restart the machine and no clue.

See the image.
[image: iis]

Comment: In case you haven't tried, right-click it and select RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR.... If that resolves, I'll be happy to add as an answer so let me know.

Comment: I tried it. Same result. By the way, my laptop has a small space in C drive. Not sure if it is the issue. I only have 2.88GB left. However I only 3 tasks running. CPU Usage is pretty small(5~7%)